# Cookie vs Set-Cookie Header in Postman

Tags: cookies, postman

Why doesn't Postman (chrome extension) support more traditional "Set-Cookie" header. I have tried sending cookies using "Set-Cookie" as key and "cookie_name=cookie_value" as value, but server did not get the cookie information.

I retried with "Cookie" as the key and it worked.

It looks like it supports "Cookie" header instead. Why "Cookie" and "Cookie 2" instead of more traditional "Set-Cookie"?

Answer (score 2):

Usually a consumer (be it a browser or Postman) sends cookies to the server via the `Cookie` header.

A server that wants to inform a consumer to set a cookie, will send it via the `Set-Cookie` header.

Source: Cisco mentions this in one of their [Q&A articles](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/web-security-appliance/117925-technote-csc-00.html)