# How to see cookies in postman?

Tags: spring-mvc, cookies, postman

This is my post login in controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = EWPRestContants.SAY_HELLO, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,produces=MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String sayHello(  HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) {
        for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
            System.out.println(cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue());
    }
    }

    Cookie newCookie = new Cookie("testCookie", "testCookieValue");
    newCookie.setMaxAge(24 * 60 * 60);
    response.addCookie(newCookie);
    return  "hello";
}
```

I see a return "hello" in the response body. The status is 200 OK. But my cookie is not intercepted. Please help me.

My postman test script is

`var cookieValue  = postman.getResponseCookie("testCookie").value;
tests["cookie-value = " + cookieValue] = true;`

Why am I not able to intercept cookie? How to get a cookie in response from the server?

Comment: It definitely seems postman has a bug with displaying cookies. I ran into this today and it appears others have seen it as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685361/cookie-vs-set-cookie-header-in-postman